# Can't add products to Category Magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento, tree, addition, product, categories

I can't add products to a category. If I like to add it, I get this view:

[image]

I see only the root category but not the subcategories. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Go To **Catalog > Manage Categories** and create sub categories under Root category . If you already created sub categories, than make sure you set Active for that sub category, than it will show an option to add products to sub categories....